# ViewControllers overlapping each other in Main.Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I've two `ViewControllers` in `Main.Storyboard`, entry point `ViewController` have green background, and another is red background. At the button click of first `ViewController` it should show second `ViewController`, but the first and second `ViewControllers` are overlapping each other and both `ViewControllers` Buttons are clickable.

[image: Ist view controller, bingo is the button]

Ist view controller (green), bingo is the `UIButton`

[image]

2nd view controller (red), hello is the `UIButton`
On the click event of the button in first view controller is :

```
MViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mvc"];
    [self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if its a push segue :

```
  MViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mvc"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

And you should take one navigation controller and assign it as initial view and make green view the root view. Delete the default root view controller comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in the action block of **bingo button**

```
{

let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let redVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("**RedViewControllerSID**") as RedViewController

self.presentViewController(redVC, animated:true, completion:nil)

}
```

go storyboard and create Storyboard ID as **RedViewControllerSID**